Prisma Client could not locate the Query Engine for runtime "darwin-arm64". on M3 Silicon
I started Prisma with introspecting a database.
I pulled all the tables and columns perfectly which maps to my schema.
After hitting the API I get the error ..
Creating Lambda functions using serverless
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const result1 = await prisma.user.findMany()



When the api is called and request reaches the above code i get the following error..
`prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:
Prisma Client could not locate the Query Engine for runtime "darwin-arm64". 

Below is the model which was introspected from the DB
model user {
  id                         Int                          @id(map: "PK_cace4a159ff9f2512dd42373760") @default(autoincrement())
  first_name                 String?                      @db.VarChar
  user_identifier            String                       @db.VarChar
  password                   String                       @db.VarChar
  is_verified                Boolean                      @default(false)
  is_blocked                 Boolean                      @default(false)
  stripe_customer_id         String                       @default("abc") @db.VarChar
  created_at                 DateTime                     @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  profileId                  Int?                         @unique(map: "REL_9466682df91534dd95e4dbaa61")
  lottery_winner             lottery_winner[]
  payments                   payments[]
  user_profile               user_profile?                @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "FK_9466682df91534dd95e4dbaa616")
  user_lottery_participation user_lottery_participation[]
  user_notifications         user_notifications[]
  user_verification_code     user_verification_code[]
}

After applying baseline it mapped to this
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "first_name" VARCHAR,
    "user_identifier" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "password" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "is_verified" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "is_blocked" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "stripe_customer_id" VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'abc',
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "profileId" INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT "PK_cace4a159ff9f2512dd42373760" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

here is the output of npx prisma -v
prisma                  : 5.19.0
@prisma/client          : 5.19.0
Computed binaryTarget   : darwin-arm64
Operating System        : darwin
Architecture            : arm64
Node.js                 : v18.20.2
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine 5fe21811a6ba0b952a3bc71400666511fe3b902f (at ../node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-darwin-arm64.dylib.node)
Schema Engine           : schema-engine-cli 5fe21811a6ba0b952a3bc71400666511fe3b902f (at ../node_modules/@prisma/engines/schema-engine-darwin-arm64)
Schema Wasm             : @prisma/prisma-schema-wasm 5.19.0-31.5fe21811a6ba0b952a3bc71400666511fe3b902f
Default Engines Hash    : 5fe21811a6ba0b952a3bc71400666511fe3b902f
Studio                  : 0.502.0


Below are generator and dbSource
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


How can i get rid of this error any valuable suggestions.?
